# Geoserver WMS distortion when reprojecting on high zoom

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, leaflet, wms

I have a GeoServer WMS that I load in a Leaflet map (keeping the map default CRS 3857) as a `L.tileLayer.wms`. The problem is that when I zoom in on this tile layer, the pixels get deformed and appear split, as shown below in the image (First img: Leaflet-map CRS: 3857; Second img: QGIS project CRS 3857). The second image is my desire result.

[image]

(Leaflet)

[image]

(QGIS)

Minimal code needed for a [reproducible example](https://plnkr.co/edit/DFQkhkJfJMq15AGD):

```
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    center: [28.3300,-16.490740],
    zoom: 15
});


L.tileLayer.wms('http://sigred.oapn.es/geoserver/SistemaREMOTE_modis/wms?',{
    layers: "SistemaREMOTE_modis:ref_prod_media_resumen",
    transparent: true,
    format: 'image/png'
}).addTo(map);
```

I tried changing the CRS of the Leaflet map to 4326, but that didn't work, and also that way my OSM basemap won't place right.

Also If I visualize the WMS with OpenLayers from GeoServer it looks correctly (http://sigred.oapn.es/geoserver/SistemaREMOTE_modis/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=SistemaREMOTE_modis:ref_prod_media_resumen&styles=&bbox=-965199.01397601,3190740.34917998,834315.241888609,4798237.84077302&width=768&height=686&srs=EPSG:25830&format=application/openlayers)

What I am doing wrong? Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant part of the code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant part of the code.

Comment: Your example of the data displaying correctly with OpenLayers from GeoServer, doesn't use either epsg:4326 or epsg:3857 as per your Leaflet or QGIS example, but EPSG:25830.

Comment: You say you have a `I have a GeoServer WMS (CRS: 4326) ` but the service isn't limited to EPSG:4326 rather supports several projections ~ EPSG:23029,EPSG:23030,EPSG:23031,EPSG:25829,EPSG:25830,EPSG:25831,EPSG:32627,EPSG:32628,EPSG:32629,EPSG:32630,EPSG:32631,EPSG:3857,EPSG:4082,EPSG:4083,EPSG:4230,EPSG:4258,EPSG:4326,CRS:84.  It appears that the default might be EPSG:23030

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a minimal example. I suspect some kind of reprojection error in the geoserver side, since I *guess* the original data is in EPSG:25830 and the distortion is more noticeable the further away from the 0° meridian.

Comment: Yeah, definitely a geoserver reprojection issue; easy to prove loading that WMS in qgis (making sure to use EPSG:3857), zooming in, and adding a vector layer with some control points. I think GeoServer is somehow rounding up coordinates to the pixel size of the source dataset. I can't say much more than that.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. Exactly. the tiff is produced in ETRS89. I'll ask my colleage how he produces the WMS. And try to reproject the tiff before publishing it. Also thank you Ivan for adding the code example, this was my first question.